# Not every month starts with monday

Tags: javascript

i'm making this simple calendar : http://jsfiddle.net/ro0wnpus/
 but not every month starts with Monday being the first date.
my question is how to find out what is the first date of the month ?

here is the function that draws the days in a month :

```
function drawDays() {
    var position = document.getElementById("daysContainer");
    var element = "<div id='cell'>";
    var numDays = getNumberOfDays(month);

    for (var i = 0; i < numDays; i++) {
        position.innerHTML += (element + (i+1) + "</div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Date - Javascript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 2):

```
var dt = new Date(); // create a date, default = today
dt.setDate(1);      // change date so it's the 1st of the month
alert(dt.getDay()); // get day-of-week, 0 = sunday ->  6 = saturday.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this ...

```
var year = "2014";
var month = "12";
var day = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-01").getDay()
```

Since you count from 1 and Monday is the first day of the week you'll also have to do this:

```
day = (day===0) ? 7 : day
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ro0wnpus/

Here are the things I changed.

Found which day of the week was the first day using `getDay()` and added a new var count which will keep track of the date in your loop. `getDay()` gives us an integer between 0 and 6 corresponding to sunday to monday.

```
var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();
var count = 1;
```

Added the first day to the total days in the month since we need to loop through more dates now

```
var numDays = getNumberOfDays(month)+firstDay;
```

Changed your loop to check when we get to the first day, if we aren't there yet, leave the spot blank

```
for (var i = 1; i < numDays; i++) {
    if(i >= firstDay){
        position.innerHTML += (element + (count) + "</div>");
        count++;
    }else{
        position.innerHTML += (element + "" + "</div>");
    }
}
```